# Receber dados de um select no Angular

Tags: angularjs

Eu estou fazendo um select para um serviço REST, usando Angular. Mas a página que deveria ter a tabela populada com os dados vindos do select, fica em branco.

Na minha página, eu possuo um input (Para digitar o nome do motorista) e um botao, que dispara a função que vai até o serviço e faz o select, então, eu mando o registro para outra página. Os dados estão voltando, pois no callback da função js, eu printo um  alert na tela, com o objeto retornado, porém, não consigo popular a minha tabela com os dados do select. Alguém saberia o porquê? desde já agradeço muito!

Minha função js que faz o link com o serviço e faz o select:

```
$scope.procurar = function (){
    var nome = $scope.filtro;
    $http.post(linkservice + "selectByNome", nome).then(function (response) {   
        $scope.nomes = response.data;
        alert($scope.nomes.texto_cnh);
        window.location.href = "resultadoBusca.jsp";
    });
}
```

Minha tabela que deveria mostrar os dados do retorno do select:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>C.P.F</th>
    <th>CNH</th>
    <th>Categoria</th>
    <th>Vencimento</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in nomes">
    <td><a ng-click = "enviarDadosDetalhe(x)">{{x.id}}</a></td>
    <td><a ng-click = "enviarDadosDetalhe(x)">{{x.cpf}}</a></td>
    <td><a ng-click = "enviarDadosDetalhe(x)">{{x.texto_cnh}}</a></td>
    <td><a ng-click = "enviarDadosDetalhe(x)">{{x.data_validade_cnh}}</a></td>

    <td>
        <div ng-if ="x.status == 'a'">
            <button ng-click = "alterarstatus(x)"> Inativar Motorista</button>
            <button ng-click = "enviarDados(x)"> Atualizar motorista </button>
        </div>
        <div ng-if ="x.status == 'i'">
            <button ng-click = "alterarstatus(x)"> Ativar Motorista</button>
            <button ng-click = "enviarDados(x)"> Atualizar motorista </button>
        </div>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.procurar = function (){
var nome = $scope.filtro;
$http.post(linkservice + "selectByNome", nome).then(function (response) {   
    $scope.nomes = response.data;
    alert($scope.nomes.texto_cnh);
    window.location.href = "resultadoBusca.jsp";
});
```

}

O response.data, você conseguiu printar a propriedade texto_cnh ?  se conseguiu, o problema pode estar ai, porque seu servidor REST não esta retornando um array, e sim um unico objeto.

Se retornar uma lista, você consegue acessar a propriedade text_cnh da forma que esta logo abaixo

```
$scope.procurar = function (){
var nome = $scope.filtro;
$http.post(linkservice + "selectByNome", nome).then(function (response) {   
    $scope.nomes = response.data;
    alert($scope.nomes[0].texto_cnh);
    window.location.href = "resultadoBusca.jsp";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

São 2 problemas:
1 - O mais grave window.location.href = "resultadoBusca.jsp"; quando chega nessa linha o navegador atualiza a url e você perde todo seu $scope;
2 - As vezes a consulta da API pode demorar então o angularjs não consegue renderizar porque o $digest já foi executado. Então use $applyAsync. porém você deve resolver o problema de atualização da janela.